# How to assign a specific private ip (pre-determined ip base on my CIDR and subnet) when create ec2 using Cloudformation script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, automation, aws-cloudformation

This the code I use, still not working. I am trying to create the instant using CloudFormation template and to be launched with specific private ip address. Please help what am I missing : where would I mention the private ip that I need it to be assigned to the instant in the CloudFormation template?

````
"Ec2Instance" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
  "Properties" : {
    "ImageId" : { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "RegionMap", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "AMI" ]},
    "KeyName" : { "Ref" : "KeyName" },
    "NetworkInterfaces": [ {
      "DeviceIndex": "0",
      "PrivateIpAddress" : String,
    } ]
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PrivateIpAddress` is where you specify the private Ip. It would be good to also specify `SubnetId` as your IP must match CIDR range of the subnet where you are placing the instance.

Example:

```
  InstanceWithFixedPirivateIp:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:                
      ImageId: ami-07ebfd5b3428b6f4d
      InstanceType: t2.micro        
      Monitoring: false            
      NetworkInterfaces:
        - DeviceIndex: 0
          PrivateIpAddress: 172.31.80.12
          SubnetId: subnet-a9e16487 # CIDR 172.31.80.0/20
```

Comment: Thank you , I had a feeling i missing something easy here , again thank you for you fast response.

Comment: I wonder how Aws deal with **Ip confliction** problem in CloudFormation? \
eg: \
CloudFormation created an ec2 `AA`, auto assign a private ip `172.31.80.12`; \
at the same time, you manually specify `172.31.80.12` for another ec2 `BB`.